# how to fix menu bar css-adapter stuffs with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i 'm working with Menu Bar in asp.net 3.5. Here i disturbed something like IE bug that doesn't show menu bar properly. i found some use full article and for fixing up menu bar problem with all browser like chrome, IE and Fire Fox :

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if ((Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0) || (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Unknown") > 0) || (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Chrome") > 0))
            {
                Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

there is problem with my IE :

[image]

I just want to solution for this menu bar with IE problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why doesn't it work with IE?

Comment: You need to add more details then... Post some code... You said you found an article, where's the link?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giorgio/archive/2009/02/01/asp-net-menu-and-ie8-rendering-white-issue.aspx

Comment: @bastos.sergio - ya just see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for putting this tag between head tag it's works:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```